# How to convert netcdf file into csv?

Tags: file-upload, powerbi, type-conversion, netcdf, file-format

I am trying to load nc4 files into Power BI but there is no option to load nc4 format into Power BI, or instead is there any way to convert nc4 files?

Comment: in power query and with python script you can change that to csv or table

Comment: You can  convert it with MTALAB, GRADS, NetCDF4Excel, Arc GIS and etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.